# Помаранчі чи апельсини?

Tags: вибір-слова

Як правильно вживати: помаранчі чи апельсини? Яке з  цих слів є найбільш доречним на письмі та в усному мовленні? Мене цікавить, чи можна слово "помаранчі" використати в офіційному мовленні. Чи це більш художній варіант?

Comment: У якому контексті? Фрукт? Колір? Ще щось? Які джерела ви знайшли самостійно, і що са́ме вас не влаштовує у тому, що ви прочитали там?

Comment: приєднуюсь до попереднього коментаря. варто розширити запитання.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [***Апельсин***](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD) — рослина виду **Citrus × sinensis** або її плоди. Англійською його називають просто *orange* або *sweet* («солодкий») *orange* (хоча останню цю назву іноді звужують до особливо солодкого різновида, також відомого як *acidless* («безкислотний») *orange*). Найчастіше плоди їдять, з них витискають сік чи роблять варення.

  Найвідоміші різновиди:

  - «звичайний» апельсин;
  - червоний апельсин (англ. *blood orange* — «кривавий апельсин»);
  - апельсин з ще одним маленьким апельсинчиком усередині (англ. *venom orange* — «пупковий апельсин»).
- [***Помаранч*** (або інакше: ***помаранча***, ***померанець***, ***бігарадія***)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C) — рослина виду **Citrus × aurantium** або її плоди. Англійською — *bitter* («гіркий») *orange*, *Seville* («севільський») *orange*, *sour* («кислий») *orange*, *bigarade orange* або *marmalade orange* (це, я так розумію, незалежно від різновида, просто багато назв). Найчастіше ці рослини і їх плоди не використовують прямо в їжу, а роблять варення і олії, а також використовують як лікарський засіб.

Апельсин і помаранч обидва є гібридами мандарина (Citrus reticulata) і помело (Citrus maxima) (причому знаходяться доволі поряд на [схемі гібридів цитрусів](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Citrus_tern_cb_simplified_1_uk.svg)) і доволі схожі візуально (світлини [апельсина](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:OrangeBloss_wb.jpg) і [помаранча](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Citrus_aurantium.jpg)).

Апельсини також часто називають помаранчами, але це значення слова «помаранч(а)» вважається **[розмовним](http://sum.in.ua/s/pomarancha)**. (Принаймні вважалося раніше. Хоча я не здивуюся, якщо «апельсин» і «помаранч(у)» скоро визнають синонімами, а конкретний вид визначатиметься просто додатковими словами — але наразі словники так не вважають.)

Доповнення:
Запитання: Чи можна слово «помаранчі» використати в офіційному мовленні?
Відповідь: Оскільки за словниками слово «помаранч(а)» означає іншу рослину/плід, то його **не варто застосовувати в офіційному мовленні** для позначення апельсина.

Comment: @Follower, переклав схему.

Comment: @Follower, «Альтмайєр», «Вейєрштрасс», «Фейєрбах», «Штайнмайєр» — за правописом, здається, так. Хоч мені це і дуже не подобається. Чи у Вас є аргументи за інше написання? («[Бергамот](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3928&page=150)». «Рангпур» дивився у Вікіпедії, хоч це, звісно, не аргумент.)

Comment: Ну, за правописом [‚є‘](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par91): _Також після апострофа, **е і й ь** пишеться є, а не е_. А про _ґ_ все сумно: ӧго просто ‚додали‘ до абетки, трохи слів і [все](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par87). Вона типу ё, але насправді її десь на рівні ‚немаё‘.

Comment: За правописом 2019 зайве _й_ відкидає ся без обговору.

Comment: @stegetsj, так, треба буде оновити схему. Якщо є бажання...

Answer (score 4):

Не дуже зрозуміло запитання. Коротко:

[Помаранча](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C) — гіркі — Citrus aurantium.

[Апельсини](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD_(%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4)) — солодкі — Citrus sinēnsis.

В [розмовному](http://sum.in.ua/s/Pomarancha) сенсі: обидва можуть позначати жовтогарячий цитрусовий плід з розміром за яблуко — обидва слова етимолоґічно включають слово „яблуко“.

---

[Малоруско-нїмецкий словар, **Львів**, 1886 • Євгений Желеховский, Софрон Недїльский](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/zheleh_slovnyk.htm)

Сторінки: 5, 695:

> **Апельси́н**, *m*. Apfelsine, *f*. (Citrus aurantiom sinensis).
>
> **Помара́нча**, *f*. Pomeranzenbaum, *m*. Orangen-Agrume, *f*. (**Citrus aurantium**)
>
> 2) Pomeranze als Frucht, *f*. помаранчаки́, *pl*. Orangen, *pl*. (Hesperides); помаранчова́тї, *pl*. Orangengewächse, Goldäpfel, *pl*. (Aurantiaceae).

Comment: Оу, перепрошую, не помітив Вашу відповідь. Як думаєте, видаляти (мою) чи хай залишається?